# createMock vs createPartialMock vs createConfiguredMock (PHP unit methods in Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

What is the difference between **createMock**, **createPartialMock** and **createConfiguredMock** methods of **PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase** class in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**createMock:**

`createMock(string $originalClassName)`

It uses the **getMockBuilder** method to create a test double for the specified class. It disables the constructor of the original class (you will almost always want to do that)

**createPartialMock:**

`createPartialMock(string $originalClassName, array $methods)`

The **createPartialMock** method is very similar to **createMock** but it lets you specify an array with a subset of methods to be mocked (**createMock** doesn't mock any method by default). This is specially useful in Magento 2 when mocking factories, since you will need the `create` method of the factory to be mocked.

Example:

```
$this->priceFactoryMock = $this->createPartialMock(
    \Magento\ProductAlert\Model\PriceFactory::class,
    ['create']
);
$this->priceFactoryMock->expects(
    $this->once()
)->method('create')->willReturn(
    $priceMock
);
```

**createConfiguredMock:**

`createConfiguredMock(string $originalClassName, array $configuration)`

Similar to **createMock** but accepts a configuration array with a list of methods and their corresponding return values. Internally, it sets the `willReturn` value for the methods specified. An example use in Magento 2 would be:

```
$this->resourceConnectionMock = $this->createConfiguredMock(
    ResourceConnection::class,
    [
        'getConnection' => $this->adapterMock,
        'getTableName'  => self::PREFIXED_TABLE_MEDIA_GALLERY_ASSET
    ]
);
```

Here, besides creating the mock for the `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection` class, we are also specifying the return values of the `getConnection` and `getTableName` methods inside that class. You would obtain the same result if you first create the mock with `createMock` and then use `willReturn` like this:

```
$this->resourceConnectionMock = $this->createMock(ResourceConnection::class);
$this->resourceConnectionMock->method('getConnection')->willReturn($this->adapterMock);
$this->resourceConnectionMock->method('getTableName')->willReturn(self::PREFIXED_TABLE_MEDIA_GALLERY_ASSET);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel